# Stopping a function based on a value

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am running a python script on a raspberry-pi.

Essentially, I would like a camera to take a picture every 5 seconds, but only if I have set a boolean to true, which gets toggled on a physical button.

initially I set it to true, and then in my while(true) loop, I want to check to see if the variable is set to true, and if so, start taking pictures every 5 seconds. The issue is if I use something like time `time.sleep(5)`, it essentially freezes everything, including the check. Combine that with the fact that I am using debouncing for the button, it then becomes impossible for me to actually toggle the script since I would have to press it exactly after the 5s wait time, right for the value check... I've been searching around and I think the likely solution would have to include threading, but I can't wrap my head around it. One kind of workaround I thought of would be to look at the system time and if the seconds is a multiple of 5, then take picture (all within the main loop). This seems a bit sketchy.

Script below:

```
### Imports
from goprocam import GoProCamera, constants
import board
import digitalio
from adafruit_debouncer import Debouncer
import os
import shutil
import time


### GoPro settings
goproCamera = GoProCamera.GoPro()


### Button settings
pin = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D12)
pin.direction = digitalio.Direction.INPUT
pin.pull = digitalio.Pull.UP
switch = Debouncer(pin, interval=0.1)



save = False #this is the variable


while(True):
    switch.update()
    if switch.fell:
        print("Pressed, toggling value")
        save = not save
        
    if save:
        goproCamera.take_photo()
        goproCamera.downloadLastMedia()
        time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Once you enter the `while(save)` block, you never change the value of `save` back to `False`, therefore you will never exit that portion of your code, which is the reason for your "frozen" state

Comment: right, I guess the 2nd while could be an if statement. The question remains though, to turn it off, I would have to precisely time the button press. Will edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing:

```
### Imports
from goprocam import GoProCamera, constants
import board
import digitalio
from adafruit_debouncer import Debouncer
import os

import time
import threading

### GoPro settings
gopro = GoProCamera.GoPro()


### Button settings
pin = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D12)
pin.direction = digitalio.Direction.INPUT
pin.pull = digitalio.Pull.UP
switch = Debouncer(pin, interval=0.1)

### Picture save location
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
new_path = dir_path+"/pictures/"

save = False

### Functions
def takePhoto(e):
    while e.isSet():
        gopro.take_photo()
        gopro.downloadLastMedia()
        fname = '100GOPRO-' + gopro.getMedia().split("/")[-1]
        current_file = dir_path+'/'+fname
        if os.path.isfile(current_file):
            os.replace(current_file, new_path+fname) #move file, would be cleaner to download the file directly to the right folder, but the API doesn't work the way I thought it did
        e.wait(5)
        

### Initial settings
        
e = threading.Event()
t1 = threading.Thread(target=takePhoto, args=([e]))

print("Starting script")
while(True):
    switch.update()
    if switch.fell:
        #toggle value
        save = not save
    if save:
        e.set() #should be taking pictures
    else:
        e.clear() #not taking pictures
        
    if not t1.is_alive(): #start the thread if it hasn't been yet
        if e.is_set():
            t1.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to try:

```
while(True):
    switch.update()
    if switch.fell:
        print("Pressed, toggling value")
        save = not save
    if save:
        current_time = time.time()
        if current_time - last_pic_time >= 5:
            goproCamera.take_photo()
            goproCamera.downloadLastMedia() 
            last_pic_time = current_time
```

Depending on exactly what sort of behavior you want, you may have to fiddle with when and how often `time.time()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Cheers!
Maybe something like this?

```
import threading

def set_interval(func, sec):
    def func_wrapper():
        set_interval(func, sec)
        func()
    t = threading.Timer(sec, func_wrapper)
    t.start()
    return t
```

We call the function above inside the main loop.

Wrap your while loop content on a function:

```
def take_photo:
    goproCamera.take_photo()
    goproCamera.downloadLastMedia()
```

Now we create a flag initially set to False to avoid creating multiple threads.
Notice that I did this before the while loop. We just need a starting value here.

```
active = False

while(True):
    switch.update()
    if switch.fell:
        print("Pressed, toggling value")
        save = not save

    if save: # we need to start taking photos.
        if not active: # it is not active... so it is the first time it is being called or it has been toggled to save as True again.
            photo_thread = set_interval(take_photo, 5) # grabbing a handle to the thread - photo_thread - so we can cancel it later when save is set to False.
            active = True # marking as active to be skipped from the loop until save is False
    else:
        try: # photo_thread may not exist yet so I wrapped it inside a try statement here.
            photo_thread.cancel() #  if we have a thread we kill it
        active = False #setting to False so the next time the button is pressed we can create a new one.
```

Let me know if it works. =)

Comment: I feel like this is a set in the right direction. I get a RunTimeError: Can't start a new thread error. The script then continues, but the button does nothing to start/stop it.

Comment: yeah Can't start a new thread error makes sense here since we are calling set interval within every loop... we need a flag or something to call it just once. i will try something here and get back to you o/

Comment: I think I have it figured out

Comment: Good. Glad it worked out. By curiosity, did my take on it still ran into thead errors?

Comment: I didn't pursue it much further, unfortunately... I did post my solution below, which works.

Comment: yeah your solution is definetly cleaner. greetings.